# Joomla, how to display contact form

Tags: joomla

I am beginner to joomla, and following is my problem:

Joomla displays content using the following tags

```
                <jdoc:include type="message" />
                <jdoc:include type="component" />
```

However, in my case, the contact form will not be displaying in the section using that above tags. Thus, is there any other ways I could display my contact form?

ie. There is a specific `<div>` where I would like my contact form to appear at, and it is not the main content holder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you show the form by creating a menu item for it. Then it will be shown withing the place specified with `<jdoc:include type="component" />` once the user clicks said menu item.

If you want to show the form outside of the main part of your site, then you need to use a module for this. Since there is no module in the core which shows a contact form, you probably need a third party module for this. Have a look at http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/contact-forms to see what is available.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a 'forms component' like http://www.chronoengine.com/downloads/9-chronoforms.html

Create your form using ChronoForms, then create a menu item, then select 'menu item type' and choose ChronoForms.

ChronoForms also offers a 'module' so you can display your form in any module position.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the contact form to work you need to have a contact with a email address defined in "Contacts".